# Vagrant - How to use nfs for all synced folders?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to instruct Vagrant (through Vagrantfile) to use `nfs` for all `synced_folder` declared.

I guess it will be something like this:

```
vm.synced_folder.each do ...
    ... use nfs
end
```

But I don't know ruby's syntax.

---

Now experimenting with:

```
  # Use nfs for better performance
  config.vm.synced_folder.each do |id, options|
    if ! options[:type]
      options[:type] = "nfs"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to declare all the sync folder you want to make and then loop through that - something like

```
sharedfolderlist = {
  "/folder_vm_1" => "folder_from_host/",
  "/folder_vm_1" => "/can_be_full_path_folder_from_host/",
}

sharedfolder.each do |vm, host|
  config.vm.synced_folder host, vm, nfs: true
end
```

Its not brilliant but could do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I need a code that acts separately (code that doesn't alter or rely on existing code)